# How to define instance/document methods on a mongoose model, without including them in the document interface

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

In the official documentation for [using mongoose with typescript](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript.html), in regards to extending the `mongoose.Document` type when providing a type definition, it states:

> This approach works, but we recommend your document interface not extend Document. Using extends Document makes it difficult for Mongoose to infer which properties are present on query filters, lean documents, and other cases.
>
> We recommend your document interface contain the properties defined in your schema and line up with what your documents look like in MongoDB. ***Although you can add instance methods to your document interface, we do not recommend doing so***.

With regards to the last line of the second paragraph, if it is recommended not to include instance/document methods in the document interface — how should we provide this information? Without defining these methods on the document interface, typescript throws an error that `Property <insert method name> does not exist on type <insert document types>`.

For example, consider the following definition for a user:

```js
// user.model.ts 
import { model, Schema } from 'mongoose';
import { UserDoc } from '../types/user.d.ts';

const userSchema = new Schema<UserDoc, Model<UserDoc>, UserDoc>({
  firstName: { type: String, required: true },
  lastName: { type: String, required: true },
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true, lowercase: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true, trim: true }
});

userSchema.virtual('fullName').get(function (this: UserDoc) {
  return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`
});

userSchema.method('getFullName', function () {
  return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`
})

export default model<UserDoc, Model<UserDoc>>('User', userSchema)
```

The `UserDoc` interface is defined as follows:

```js
export interface UserDoc {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
}
```

Without explicitly defining the `fullName` virtual property or the `getFullName` instance method on the `UserDoc` interface, neither can be accessed.

For example, consider the following express route handler to register a new user:

```js
import { RequestHandler } from 'express';
import User from '../models/user.model.ts'; // The model as defined in the above userSchema

const registerUserHandler: RequestHandler = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { firstName, lastName, email, password } = req.body;

  if (await User.exists({ email })) {
    return res.status(400).json('Email already exists')
  }

  const newUser = await User.create({ firstName, lastName, email, password });

  console.log(newUser.fullName)       // This will cause typescript error
  console.log(newUser.getFullName())  // This will cause typescript error

  return res.status(201).json('User created')
}
```

However, if the `UserDoc` interface is extended to include the `fullName` virtual and the `getFullName` method, typescript won't error and will allow access.

When looking at the official documentation for [static methods](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript/statics.html), it states that you must include these and extend the `mongoose.Model<T>` interface.

So, if we aren't supposed to put these on the document interface, how are we supposed to define them so that typescript can allow access?